# User can upload images, i.e. profile picture - what are some best practices?

Tags: android, ios, image-uploading, image-size

Looking for a little advice here for both iOS and Android apps.

The scenario is rather simple, let's say we allow the user of an iOS or Android app to upload an image that we'll use as their profile picture. What are the best practices around down-sampling the image before posting to the server.

For example, in iOS we create assets at x1, x2, x3 and in Android we produce assets in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. Do we do the same with an image that's uploaded by the user?

What do you do in your app for a similar/same scenario? If we downsample, we intend to do this in the clients rather than on the server. Just not sure if we need to convert the image to all the different sizes as required by each platform.

For the purposes of this experiment, let's say the final profile picture image will be 200x200 on the client.

Comment: i think no.. for uploading any image to server no such practice is required. As well as for one image the uploading query will take time. And if you make assets first and then upload the format your uploading time will increase depending upon the size of the images

Comment: If we allow users to upload photos from the client apps, should we scale them accordingly to x1, x2, x3 (iOS) and mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi (Android)? Or do we simply store one version of the image. What is best practice when allowing users to upload photos... does Instagram create 7 different version/sizes of each image to display on different screen pixel densities?

Comment: i think - for iOS simply store one version and upload. Can't say about android but its easy and faster way to store one version and upload it